# Macbook Air backlight occasionally powering off

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, display

Started a few months ago, and it's definitely not to do with sleep mode as I've checked but my MBA will drop the backlight then shut the screen off completely. Never had anything spilt on it, seems to occur most frequently when it's being opened (but that's not guaranteed). Hardware fault or something else? Nothing in the Console logs suggesting software weirdness.

EDIT: Because I was an idiot I didn't post the most useful info ;)

Macbook Air is a 2010 Core2Duo, the release *just* before the Core i series ones.

Running latest Snow Leopard.

Comment: What OS? Have you tried the good ole [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)? Any noticeable case damage?

Comment: Which MacBook Air do you have?

Comment: Added the info into the question :) No case damage, not tried the SMC reset yet, wanted to just canvas opinion on what seemed most likely.